# PHP Regex: match specific length of string on repeated char

Tags: php, regex

I'm playing with regex and i try used this pattern `/\(\((.+?)\)\w+/` to match string that i want.

This is my string

> (string,love) (string,string string string(string,string
>   string,string),string) (string string string(string,string string))
>   (string,string) ((string,string string)string,string)

i expect

> (string,string string)string

What i got is

> ((string,string string)string

I need to match just one '(' symbol, not two '(('.

How to achieve that? Thank you

Comment: You need `/\(\(([^()]+)\)\w+/`, you need to use `[^()]+` to *match a substring inside parentheses excluding any inner parentheses*.

Comment: I think what you're actually looking for is a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match but not capture the first parenthesis. Albeit just making the appropriate capture group or stripping the remnant opening `(` would be simpler.